# When echo command used, shows up 0 instead of nothing

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a little project and came across (big suprise) another issue.
Here is the code that has something to do with the echo command:

```
@echo off
set /a project=nothing
echo The current project is %project%
pause
exit
```

When the file is run, it says:

> "The current project is 0"

Anyone know what my problem might be?

Comment: `set /?` will tell you that `set /a` is for numerical expressions.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this! Sorry, new to programming. Will set project=nothing work?

Comment: Try it :) (spoiler: yes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set /a` is for setting numerical values based on expressions, such as:

```
pax> set /a "pi10k = 39270000 / 1250"
31416
```

If you just want to set it to a *string,* use:

```
set project=nothing
```

---

As per the output of `set /?`:

> `SET /A expression`
>
> The `/A` switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
>   is a numerical expression that is evaluated.  The expression evaluator
>   is pretty simple and supports the following operations, in decreasing
>   order of precedence:

```
()                  - grouping
! ~ -               - unary operators
* / %               - arithmetic operators
+ -                 - arithmetic operators
<< >>               - logical shift
&                   - bitwise and
^                   - bitwise exclusive or
|                   - bitwise or
= *= /= %= += -=    - assignment
  &= ^= |= <<= >>=
,                   - expression separator
```

> If you use any of the logical or modulus operators, you will need to
>   enclose the expression string in quotes.
>
> **Any non-numeric strings in the expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are converted to numbers before using them.  If an environment variable name is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value of zero is used.**  This allows you to do arithmetic with environment variable values without having to type all those `%` signs to get their values.
>
> If `SET /A` is executed from the command line outside of a command script, then it displays the final value of the expression.  The assignment operator requires an environment variable name to the left of the assignment operator.  Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by `0x` for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers. So `0x12` is the same as `18` is the same as `022`. Please note that the octal notation can be confusing: `08` and `09` are not valid numbers because `8` and `9` are not valid octal digits.

The bold bit in the text above is the bit that causes it to be set to zero, assuming you have no environment variable called `nothing`. If you *do* have such a variable, its value is used instead:

```
pax> set /a xyzzy=plugh
0
pax> set plugh=42

pax> set /a xyzzy=plugh
42
```

Comment: Thanks, but Blorgbeard beat you to it!

Comment: @Jared, yes, but what  Blorgbeard appears to miss is that you're meant to "use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer" (as per http://stackoverflow.com/tour), not as a way to _actually_ answer. Since they've been here about as long as I, I would have thought they'd know that by now :-) Comments have always been treated as second-class citizens here, it's a Q&A site, not a Q&A&C one. Either the question is a good one in which case it deserves an _answer,_ or it's not, in which case it should be closed and deleted (and comments are irrelevant).

Comment: Yes, since he didn't post an answer, I guess you win the award of "the little green check mark", Come to the stand and take your prize! *audience clap*

Comment: If you want to award the little green check mark to someone else, feel free. In fact, I often bypass the accepted answers and look at the highest voted - I've always thought the questioner the least able to know the best answer, else they wouldn't be asking the question. Perhaps BB could even expand on their comment. I don't care, as long as the questions and answers here are good. It's not like I actually _get_ anything from a high rep, other than the odd coffee mug and such :-)

Comment: Well, since I signed up for stackoverflow on saturday (yesterday) I can't give you any rep. If I could, I would! Thanks.

Comment: +1'd. I admit, I'm often too lazy to post a full answer like the above, and (mis)use comments instead. I should cut it out.